# Calling Struts 2 method from JavaScript without AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, struts2

I am trying to call an action method from JavaScript but without using AJAX.
Is that possible?

Actually I am trying to render a PDF in the web browser. Earlier I used AJAX to call action and then read the PDF file in that action class, and set the response with `setContentType("application/pdf")`. But it was not rendering on the screen as AJAX will send back the response to JavaScript.

One more thing, is there any way I can call open a new pop up browser window to display the "result" of action class?

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use AJAX?

Comment: How are you trying to do that?